# Are there any node library to create memory streams similar to file streams?

Tags: node.js

I use officegen library to create a docx file, then I need to zip it and return as the response. I can easily save the docx file and then create a zip file and return, but are there any alternative way to write docx file to something like memory stream instead of file streams and create a zip file?

Following code I tried with memory-streams library, this is not working. I think WritableStream is not similar to file stream. So if you replace WritableStream with output of createWriteStream, its working.

```
var streams = require('memory-streams');
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

var writer = new streams.WritableStream();

writer.on('close', function() {
    var zip = new AdmZip();
    zip.addFile("test2.docx", writer.toBuffer());
    var willSendthis = zip.toBuffer();
    return res.end(Buffer.from(willSendthis, 'binary'))
})

writer.on('error', function(){
    console.log("error")
})

doc.on('error', function(){
    console.log("error")
})

doc.generate(writer);
```

This is not something very specific to officegen, it just needs a writable stream similar to a file stream with close 'event'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following library is better than the one you are using.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/memorystream

Example:

```js
var MemoryStream = require('memorystream');
var memStream = new MemoryStream(['Hello',' ']);

var data = '';
memStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk.toString();
});  

memStream.write('World');

memStream.on('end', function() {
    // outputs 'Hello World!'
    console.log(data);
});
memStream.end('!');
```